# How to display data from mysql database to specific text fields of html page

Tags: node.js

I have username and password stored in mysql database. I want to fetch it and display username in the username field and password from database in the password textfield. But its not working.Being a beginner i don't know how to do this. This is my code where i want to display data.

```
<body>
        <div class="login-form">
            <h1>Login Form</h1>
            <form >
                <input type="text" name="name">
                <input type="password" name="pwd" required>
                
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
```

This is the node.js file.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var http=require('http');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : 'root',
    database : 'nodelogin'
});

var app = express();
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    
con.query("SELECT username,password FROM accounts", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    response.send(result);
  });
});
});
app.listen(3000);
```

This is the database

[image: .js]

I want to show values in these two fields

[image]

This is output i am getting
[image]

Comment: Add your javascript code please , We need to see what is making the GET request

Comment: @BarLevin i have attached the .js file node file code that i have right now, it is showing the output that i have attached above but i want the username and password to be shown separately in the first and second fields.

Comment: I can see your html file and node.js file , but where is your javascript file ? how do you make the GET request ? Ajax request ? Fetch request ?

Comment: this is what i want.All i am getting on internet is related to php. How can i proceed using ajax or what?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an ajax request to your javascript file , plus make sure you have a jquery CDN added on your `<head></head>` tag - you can find it here https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json', // added data type
    success: function(res) {
     // here you get the response from the server side // 
     // res.username + res.password
    }
    });
```

Now after you get your response , you want to add an ID to your inputs so you can insert a value with getElementById

`document.getElementById("password").value = res.passwword;`

This goes inside the success part of the ajax request.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: No , this code goes in your javascript file or in your html file inside a `<script></script>` tag @palo